# How do I parse this XML file from Blip.tv?

Tags: php, xml

How do I get `blip:picture` and `blip:embedUrl` from the following XML:

```
<rss xmlns:blip="http://blip.tv/dtd/blip/1.0">
  <channel>
    <item>
      <blip:picture>http://blip.tv/skin/blipnew/placeholder_user.gif</blip:picture>
      <blip:embedUrl type="application/x-shockwave-flash">http://blip.tv/play/gvsIgeevJAI</blip:embedUrl>
    </item
  </channel>
</rss>
```

The full XML feed is here:

> http://blip.tv/rss/3790656

**Solution:**

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result);

$thumbnail = $xml->xpath('channel/item/blip:picture');

$thumbnail = $thumbnail[0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$xml is a SimpleXMLElement, and you can use the [xpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) function to retrieve your information.

```
$picture  = $xml->xpath('item/blip:picture');
$embedUrl = $xml->xpath('item/blip:embedUrl');
```

Answer (score 0):

By [Reading The Fancy Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

[edit, in response to yours]

There is no such thing as custom tags in XML. Or actually, they all are custom *elements*. There are no fixed tags, unlike in XHTML, which is a special structure, describing HTML-specific elements in an XML structure.

Comment: title isn't a standard element either. It is in HTML but not in XML. `blip` is a namespace and isn't itself part of the element. It only sets that picture element apart from other picture elements, if there are any. You can try looking up `xpath` in that manual. It allows you to easily write a sort of queries to get a specific element, including namespace specification. It is very convenient to read xml files using xpath.